Actual RAM usage of Linux system
I wanted to check RAM usage of my workstation but seems like I missed something. My system has 256 Gb of RAM (Ubuntu 20.04), absolutely no workload, htop says 4.7 Gb is used. Ok, but I need to know what it is used for, and that's what I've got:
I used slabtop and got 1.037 Gb is used for kernel slabs. I used ps aux output, summed RSS column of each process and got another 1.481 Gb (2.518 Gb total).
The system has zfs installed, but no pools presented. Checked arc_summary just in case: cache size 42 kB. LVM is also installed, but I'm not sure if it has hidden RAM usage like ZFS ARC-cache.
My question is: what else I missed? 4.7 Gb - 2.5 Gb = 2.2 Gb is using somewhere in system.
P.S. You may say "why do you care of these 2.2 Gb of RAM when you have 256 Gbs?". Well, this is a demo workstation. I just need the way to measure actual RAM usage, and I need to know which peart of system is using the memory.
P.P.S. Some output:
free -h output
/proc/meminfo output
vmstat -s output
top output
slabtop output

Usually Linux uses some ram to buffer things it reads, to optimize speed, and that part is readily reclaimable if needed.

@OlivierDulac any proofs? Where can i see this value? This answer is okay but I need some numeric info from linux system itself
